# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError thrown on change detection when TemplatePortal attached to parents PortalOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have the following component structure: `App -> GrandParent -> Parent -> Child`.

1. The ChildComponennt declares a `<ng-template cdkPortal>` in its template.
2. AppComponent, GrandParentComponent and ParentComponent each declares a `<ng-template cdkPortalOutput>` in their respective templates.

Now, if the the ChildComponent attaches its portal property:

- ... to the ParentComponent - everything works as expected. You can update the `input[text]` and the change nicely propagates down into the TemplatePortal.
- to the GrandParentComponent - the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is thrown during the first change detection run. Every subsequent update in `input[text]` results in the same error. The state of the TemplatePortal is "one step behind" (meaning - if I type "abc" into the input, the value in TemplatePortal equals "ab")
- to the AppComponent - same behaviour as GrandParentComponent except for the initial error.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/portal-cdk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts (uncomment calls in `ChildComponent#ngOnInit`)

Does somebody have an explanation for this behaviour? What would be the proper way to use the CDK's portal to display a TemplatePortal in a PortalOutlet located a couple of components above?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find solution to your problem and If anyone knows, I'm interested as well, however at least I created workaround for you. It doesn't use `cdk-portal`, just Angular's `viewContainerRef`, but I belive `cdk-portal` uses similar approach.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/portal-cdk-uiyxhn
(uncomment calls in `ChildComponent#ngOnInit`)

Comment: great. thank you very much! I am marking this as an answer since it solves the problem I am facing here, but still I woud also be interested how to achieve this using cdkPortal.